# Restricting access with PAM - sufficient vs. required

Tags: ssh, pam

I'm trying to restrict SSH access to certain groups, plus the users specified in a file. The groups are listed in /etc/ssh/user.allow, and the groups in /etc/ssh/group.allow. I've tried using the following lines in /etc/pam.d/sshd:

```
auth sufficient /lib/security/pam_listfile.so onerr=fail item=user sense=allow file=/etc/ssh/user.allow 
auth required /lib/security/pam_listfile.so onerr=fail item=group sense=allow file=/etc/ssh/group.allow
```

I can't figure out how to arrange the lines, and where to use "required" and "sufficient". Any tips?

EDIT: I guess my question is, is there any way to "OR" two pam.d statements? It seems like PAM is setup to just "AND" statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"It depends". You have multiple options, which one makes sense dependends on where in the stack they are, and what effect you want. Since you only post the snippet, and not your entire config, I can think of two off the top of my head:

- You can mark them both "sufficient". That tag means that a match will stop evaluation (later lines will not be processed at all - so any password or key checks need to have happened above). That's what "sufficient" means, it's sufficient to let you in. On the other hand, a failure won't be held against you; so if the first line succeeds, you're in, if it fails, it won't be held against you and the second line is checked.
- You can use the extended syntax to mark the first as "ok to fail, but if it succeeds, skip the next one", something like:

  `auth [success=1 default=ignore] /lib/security/pam_listfile.so item=user ...`
  `auth [success=ok default=die] /lib/security/pam_listfile.so item=group ...`

  to skip the group check if the user check succeeds, but to fail of the group check also fails (and stop evaluation, "bad" instead of "die" to process later modules anyway).

The extended syntax version will probably require more actions to be specified (`man pam.conf` - http://linux.die.net/man/5/pam.conf), and you definitely need to be careful editing pam configs, because it's perfectly possible to lock yourself out of your system completely (generally, if you're editing the file, keep it open in the editor and try logging on or doing whatever you're configuring in a separate terminal). Be aware that it's also possible to completely accidentally configure your system to be overly permissive (e.g. an early "sufficient" line may skip both your environment setup and your password checks, or whatever).